# Search txt file line by line into variable and for each value run CURL command

Tags: python, bash, jira-rest-api

I filtered issues without subtasks by python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import json
sys.stdout = open('output.txt','wt')

datapath = sys.argv[1]
data = json.load(open(datapath))

for issue in data['issues']:
        if len(issue['fields']['subtasks']) == 0:
                print(issue['key'])
```

in output.txt tasks without subtasks are stored (and it works fine):

TECH-729
TECH-124

Now have different issue, it seems values in $p variable isn't passed to CURL (able to login to JIRA but not to create subtasks):

```
 while read -r p; do
  echo $p

curl -D- -u user:pass -X POST --data "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"TECH\"},\"parent\":{\"key\":\"$p\"},\"summary\":\"TestChargen#Nr\",\"description\":\"some description\",\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"Sub-task\"},\"customfield_10107\":{\"id\":\"10400\"}}}" -H "Content-Type:application/jso#n" https://jira.companyu.com/rest/api/latest/issue/

done <output.txt
```

echo output is as it should

TECH-731
TECH-729 (so curl should run twice for every output value

But curl just logs in without creating subtasks, when hardcoding instead of $p then curl executes twice for same project ID

Comment: suggestions: 1) see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for better way of reading file input.. 2) https://www.shellcheck.net/ would help in catching common issues

Comment: First, the above code is an example of ANTI-coding. Second, post the input json and the final expected result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, just posted a link to JSON file and desired output

Comment: @Milister Don’t put ‘solved’ in the title. Questions are considered solved when an answer is accepted.

Comment: @Biffen it works for me :)

Answer (score -1):

Really don't know why,but this code worked, thanks everyone

```
for project in `cat output.txt`; do
echo $project
curl -D- -u user:pass -X POST --data "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"TECH\"},\"parent\":{\"key\":\"$project\"},\"summary\":\"TestChargenNr\",\"description\":\"some description\",\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"Sub-task\"},\"customfield_10107\":{\"id\":\"10400\"}}}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://jira.company.com/rest/api/latest/issue/

 done
```